# TCP destination port is not showing 80

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

when I direct to a website the destination port(website server port) must be 80 as I read but on wireshark I could not get tcp port 80.

**1**   0.000000    23.57.209.221   192.168.0.102   TCP 60  **443 → 49856** [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0

Comment: port 443 is https.

Comment: Thank you I get it.But i have doubt. Wireshark show      Source Port: 443  Destination Port: 51272
But destination port should be 443

Comment: K I get the answer.Thank you for answering tkausl.